# Django: How to count objects from subquery filtered by ArrrayField

Tags: django, postgresql, subquery, django-queryset

I have three models linked by ForegnKeys. For the sake of example let`s say they look like this:

```
class Study(models.Model):
    obligatory_assignments = fields.ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=32), default=list, blank=True)

class Student(models.Model):
    study = models.ForeignKey('Study', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Assignment(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey('Student', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
```

For a given `Student` I need to query the number of theirs assignments with `type` given by `obligatory_assignments` in `Study` model. Additionally if a student has multiple assignemts with the same name, each `name` i want to count only once.

So far the best i figure out was to use custom `Subquery` in something like this:

```
class SubqueryCount(Subquery):
    template = "(SELECT count(*) FROM (%(subquery)s) _count)"
    output_field = PositiveIntegerField()

subquery = Assignment.objects.filter(student=OuterRef('pk'),
                                     type__in=OuterRef('study__obligatory_assignments')
                         ).order_by('name').distinct('name').values('name')

Student.objects.all().annotate(assignments_count=SubqueryCount(subquery))
```

However postgres complains about the use of `IN` operator:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: operator does not exist: character varying = character varying[]
LINE 1: ...udent_id" = ("study_student"."id") AND U0."type" IN ("stud...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I tried a few diferent solution using lookups like `__contains`, but the only thing that changed was diferrent operator error.

I would really appreciate for any suggestions or solutions ;)
DB: PostgreSQL